# How to hide and show alert div upon submit Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied most of the code below (and modified some) from a tutorial as I am new to coding and Bootstrap, I would like to know how to hide and then show the alert div telling users "Success! Well done its submitted" when the form contents are successfully posted.

```
<?php
require("includes/config.php"); //connection to DB and session start
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user fills out fields 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { die("Please enter a username."); } 
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { die("Please enter a password."); } 
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); } 

    // Check if the username is already taken
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex-  
>getMessage()); } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This username is already in use"); } 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex- 
>getMessage());} 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); } 

    // Add row to database 
    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt, 
            :email 
        ) 
    "; 

    // Security measures
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ $password = hash('sha256',   
    $password . $salt); } 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex-
>getMessage()); } 
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="">

<title>Sign Up</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script  
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">   
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>

        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable hidden">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            Success! Well done its submitted.
        </div>

        <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label> 
        <input name="username" type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

         <!--<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
         <input name="username" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email address" required autofocus>-->
         <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
         <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
         <div class="checkbox"> 
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
             </label>
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Create Account</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with javascript. Put the "Success! Well done its submitted" text in a paragraph and give it an id . For example `<p id="AfterSubmission">insert text here</p>` . Now you can select it in javascript. After this make 1 class in CSS so that we can hide the DOM element, for example:

```
.ClassThatHides{
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}
```

Now add a function to that button :

```
<button  type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="myFunction()" aria-hidden="true">
  &times;
</button>
```

And now make a javascript function that when that button is pressed it gives a class to the paragraph in question :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("AfterSubmission").setAttribute("class", "ClassThatHides");
}
</script>
```

Now it should hide. If you want the whole div to be hidden give that div the id AfterSubmission , or any id for that matter but don't forget to change it in myFunction() also since that selects it

Comment: @Lucian_Tarna thanks a lot however what I wanted was to reveal the hidden success div upon the user successfully posting the form. Your solution reveals the div upon the button being clicked

Comment: Hmmm I do not know php to help you with that. But in Ruby on Rails there is something like flash messages try to search for something like that in php

Comment: Or you could always select your element and give it the class only if the info was submited with success from php (I am sure php has selectors like those). You should add php tag :D so more people will help you